# Flowers in the Window: An Exercise in Using Classes and Objects in Rust

Tags: object-oriented, rust, simulation

### The Problem

As part of my doomed efforts to learn **Rust**, I decided to get to grips with how the language handles **classes** and **objects**. But, instead of taking on some well-known exercise, I thought it would be more fun to try to answer a question which has been nibbling at the back of my mind since I was eleven or twelve...

What is this question? The Wikipedia page for the song [**"Flowers in the Window"**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flowers_in_the_Window) by Scottish rock band Travis describes the video like this:

> The video features the band walking around a small town where all the residents are pregnant women. The band enter a clinic where women are staying and begin to perform the song. A chained-up man in distress appears at the end of the video.

The question which has fascinated me for two decades is: **Would such a community actually be feasible, from a mathematical point of view? And, if so, what is the mathematical limit on its size?** My answer to this involves simulating the scenario with

### The Code

#### main.rs

```rust
/// This is the entry point to the program.

// Declare local modules.
mod female;
mod gynaeceum;
mod utils;

/// This is where the magic happens.
fn main() {
    let mut gynaeceum = gynaeceum::Gynaeceum::new();

    gynaeceum.run_sim();
}
```

#### female.rs

```rust
/// This code defines the Female class.

// Local imports.
use crate::utils;

// Local constants.
const PROB_FALLING_PREGNANT_PER_COPULATION: f64 = 0.05;
const PROB_FEMALE_OFFSPRING: f64 = 0.5;
const LENGTH_OF_PREGNANCY_IN_DAYS: i32 = 270;
const LENGTH_OF_YEAR_IN_DAYS: i32 = 365;
const MIN_FERTILE_AGE_IN_DAYS: i32 = 15*LENGTH_OF_YEAR_IN_DAYS;
const MAX_FERTILE_AGE_IN_DAYS: i32 = 45*LENGTH_OF_YEAR_IN_DAYS;

// Helper enum.
#[derive(PartialEq)]
pub enum FemaleStatusCode {
    Normal,
    GivenBirth,
    Infertile
}

/// Structure.
pub struct Female {
    id: i32,
    age_in_days: i32,
    is_pregnant: bool,
    days_of_pregnancy: i32
}

/// Implementation.
impl Female {
    pub fn new(id: i32) -> Female {
        let result =
            Female {
                id: id,
                age_in_days: 0,
                is_pregnant: false,
                days_of_pregnancy: 0
            };

        return result;
    }

    pub fn set_age(&mut self, new_age_in_days: i32) {
        self.age_in_days = new_age_in_days;
    }

    pub fn can_copulate(&mut self) -> bool {
        if
            self.is_pregnant ||
            self.age_in_days < MIN_FERTILE_AGE_IN_DAYS ||
            self.age_in_days > MAX_FERTILE_AGE_IN_DAYS
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    pub fn copulate(&mut self) -> bool {
        if self.is_pregnant {
            return false;
        }

        if utils::happens(PROB_FALLING_PREGNANT_PER_COPULATION) {
            self.is_pregnant = true;

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    pub fn give_birth(&mut self) -> bool {
        self.is_pregnant = false;
        self.days_of_pregnancy = 0;

        if utils::happens(PROB_FEMALE_OFFSPRING) {
            return true; // I.e. has given birth to a girl.
        }

        return false; // I.e. has given birth to a boy.
    }

    pub fn tick(&mut self) -> FemaleStatusCode {
        self.age_in_days += 1;

        if self.is_pregnant {
            if self.days_of_pregnancy > LENGTH_OF_PREGNANCY_IN_DAYS {
                return FemaleStatusCode::GivenBirth;
            } else {
                self.days_of_pregnancy += 1;
            }
        } else if self.age_in_days > MAX_FERTILE_AGE_IN_DAYS {
            return FemaleStatusCode::Infertile;
        }

        return FemaleStatusCode::Normal;
    }

    pub fn get_id(&mut self) -> i32 {
        return self.id;
    }
}
```

#### gynaeceum.rs

```rust
/// This code defines a class which models "the Gynaeceum".

// Standard imports.
use std::collections::HashMap;

// Non-standard imports.
use rand::seq::SliceRandom;

// Local imports.
use crate::female;

// Local constants.
const SIM_LENGTH_IN_DAYS: i32 = 365*1000;
const SIM_INITIAL_FEMALE_COUNT: i32 = 4;
const FOUNDING_FEMALE_AGE_IN_DAYS: i32 = 365*20;

/// Structure.
pub struct Gynaeceum {
    duration_in_days: i32,
    next_ticket: i32,
    females: HashMap<i32, female::Female>
}

/// Implementation.
impl Gynaeceum {
    pub fn new() -> Gynaeceum {
        let result = 
            Gynaeceum {
                duration_in_days: 0,
                next_ticket: 1,
                females: HashMap::new()
            };

        return result;
    }

    fn get_ticket(&mut self) -> i32 {
        let result = self.next_ticket;

        self.next_ticket += 1;

        return result;
    }

    fn add_female(&mut self) {
        let mut new_female = female::Female::new(self.get_ticket());

        self.females.insert(new_female.get_id(), new_female);
    }

    fn process_retirees(&mut self, retiree_ids: Vec<i32>) {
        for id in retiree_ids {
            self.females.remove(&id);
        }
    }

    fn service(&mut self, available: Vec<i32>) -> bool {
        if available.len() == 0 {
            return false;
        }

        let selected_id = available.choose(&mut rand::thread_rng());
        let selected = self.females.get_mut(selected_id.unwrap()).unwrap();

        selected.copulate();

        return true;
    }

    fn tick(&mut self) {
        let mut available = Vec::new();
        let mut retiree_ids = Vec::new();
        let mut birth_count = 0;

        for (id, female) in self.females.iter_mut() {
            let status_code = female.tick();

            if status_code == female::FemaleStatusCode::GivenBirth {
                if female.give_birth() {
                    birth_count += 1;
                }
            } else if status_code == female::FemaleStatusCode::Infertile {
                retiree_ids.push(*id);
            } else if status_code == female::FemaleStatusCode::Normal {
                if female.can_copulate() {
                    available.push(*id);
                }
            }
        }

        for _ in 0..birth_count {
            self.add_female();
        }

        self.process_retirees(retiree_ids);
        self.service(available);
        self.duration_in_days += 1;
    }

    pub fn run_sim(&mut self) {
        for _ in 0..SIM_INITIAL_FEMALE_COUNT {
            self.add_female();
        }

        for (_, female) in self.females.iter_mut() {
            female.set_age(FOUNDING_FEMALE_AGE_IN_DAYS);
        }

        while self.duration_in_days <= SIM_LENGTH_IN_DAYS {
            self.tick();
        }

        println!("Female count: {}", self.females.len());
    }
}
```

#### utils.rs

```rust
/// This code defines some utility functions.

// Standard import.
use rand::Rng;

/// Decide randomly whether an event with a given probability happens.
pub fn happens(event_probability: f64) -> bool {
    if rand::thread_rng().gen_range(0.0..1.0) < event_probability {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

### The Results

- After sufficiently many days, the population seems to level off at around 400.
- If one tinkers with the constant `PROB_FALLING_PREGNANT_PER_COPULATION`, any increase or decrease will result in a directly proportional change in the population limit.
- Tinkering with the other constants did not result in any appreciable change in the population limit.

Answer (score 3):

Not taking the bait on you choice of examples.  The two problems with the code itself that jumped out at me first are:

If all you’re doing is giving each person a unique numeric identifier, you should be storing them in a `Vec`, not a `HashMap`, which has much higher overhead. The key should be the index within the `Vec`.

You don’t need to create a separate `crate` for each `struct`.  The name of the `struct` is a namespace. Here, there’s no point, because you have a data structure that’s only used in one block of code, which uses its internals and has no name conflicts.  So it’s an internal implementation detail of the same `crate`, not some separate library you’ll want to re-use in other projects. If you do want to group several things together in the same namespace within a crate, declare a `module`.

Comment: Forgive me for a very very late reply to your insightful answer. I have a couple of follow-up questions, if that's okay with you?

Comment: (1) I used a `HashMap` rather than a `Vec` to dodge any mind-bending bugs with adding and removing specific items within `for` loops. Do you still think I made the wrong choice? If you know a better way, I'm genuinely eager to hear it.

Comment: (2) So I declared a `crate` in the code whenever I wanted to import from another file in the same folder. I couldn't get any other syntax that did the same thing to compile. If you of a better way, could you flesh it out with a bit more of a snippet?